# JavaScript composite component nested forms

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have a simple composite component, which is nested in some form etc. I would like to bind the `click` event for all radio buttons in the `<h:selectOneRadio>` of this composite component. I am trying to bind this event by `name` property of inputs which will be created after `<h:selectOneRadio id>`. Unfortunetly it is nested, so this code doesn't work, because the generated radio button ID is like:

```
"form:someid:someid:someid etc ect."
```

Composite component code:

```
<cc:implementation>
    <..some forms etc.>
        <h:selectOneRadio id="#{cc.attrs.id}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
            <cc:insertChildren/>
        </h:selectOneRadio>
    </..some forms etc.>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */

        $('input[name=#{cc.attrs.id}]').click(function() {
                console.log("click");

        });

    /* ]]> */
    </script>
</cc:implementation>
```

Client code:

```
<mycomps:radio id="testID" ... >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="test" itemValue="false"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="test2" itemValue="true"/>
</mycomps:radio>
```

Comment: Where did you learn about using `id="#{cc.attrs.id}"` that way? This absolutely doesn't make any sense. This is however not the first time I see someone attempting to set the ID as such, so there must be somewhere out on the Internet a terribly bad resource whose author needs to be contacted and informed about this misinformation.

Comment: I just saw it in many examples, whats wrong with that ?

Comment: Which examples? It's wrong because it's not making any sense. You're merely repeating the composite's own ID in the child. Just use `id="radio"` or so. Rightclick, *View Source* in browser and so on.

Comment: It wont be any problem if i use 10x of this component on xhtml(when id seted to radio?). I still dont know how to get id of this selectOneRadio from outside composite component

Comment: You just give each composite an unique ID like as you already do for normal JSF components.